# WPF GUI starving network messages

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a Window7, C#/WPF based GUI using Blend/XAML and I want to show H.264 video which I get from the RTP stream of a video call. I am using a C based open source library for making the video call. I have created an unmanaged code DLL which is using this C based library to make the video call. P-INvoke from the WPF GUI to the DLL works fine.

However I notice that the WPF GUI is starving the network thread which is used to make calls and send/receive network messages. Is there a way to get around this problem? Remember I am using XAML (not code) for the wpf GUI.

Comment: Some code and more specifics (which library, threading in use, etc) will likely help.

Comment: Win32 Threads created by CreateThread in the C library used in Dll. Cant name the library due to proprietary reasons.

Comment: If your unmanaged code is handling all of the network communication, why would you blame the WPF front-end?  Is it hitting the network for other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create new delegate, and pass it to unmanaged thread. 
Such as:

```
public delegate int PassH264Stream(byte[] buffer, int len);
public PASSH264Stream TestDelegate = {};

TestDelegate += (buffer, len) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()
  => ReceiveInUiThread(buffer, len)), DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

and then you pass the TestDelegate into unmanaged thread through PInvoke. The idea is to have unmanaged thread call your UI thread and post stuff to message loop, without blocking UI.